# Why python loop for matrix (from lists) with changing element gives not correct output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, matrix

Personally for me, this code gives strange output, I don't understand why.

Input:

```
matrix = [[0] * 5] * 5

for i in range(5):
    matrix[i][0] = i

matrix
```

Output:

```
[[4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Basically, you're multiplying a list.  Lists in python are by reference, so when you update 1 you're updating all of them.  A way around this is list comprehensions:  `matrix = [[0] * 5 for a in range(5)]`.  The included link will be quite useful though.